# Is it possible to call a function on pageload

Tags: javascript, html, function, pageload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

```
script type="text/javascript">
function ip(ban, win) {

    var width = 15;
    var height = 10;

    if (newwin) {



}

</script>
</head>
<b><input type="button" value="Check" onclick="banow();"/></center></b>
```

Does anyone know if it is possible and how to make this function start on page load, preferably with a interval?
I am new to all this, extra help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into the `window.onload` handler and the `setInterval` function?

Comment: I wish I knew more about scripting or w/e. I have no clue about how to use the window.onload handler.
Any suggestions where to go to learn about it or something? :O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(banow, 2000);
};
```

Comment: How exactly would i place this in my page/ or where? -.-

Comment: It's JavaScript, so you put it in a `<script>` block. When the page is done loading, the `window.onload` function is called and this code runs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the amazing answer, quick response, thank everyone else also. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `onload` event, apply the `onload` event to an event listener, or put a `()` right after the closing curly bracket of your function.

```
//e.g. 1:
window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    function_to_call();
  }, 1000);
};

//e.g. 3:
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    function_to_call();
  }, 1000);
}, false);


//e.g. 2:
function function_to_call(){

}();
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$(function(){
     // your methods here, will be called after page has been loaded
     setInterval(functionName, 1000); //replace functionName with your function, 1000 is millisecond
});
```

Comment: jQuery is a lightweight "write less, do more" JavaScript library.  So you want "write more", ok fine.  What's with the attitude anyway?

Comment: [When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)

Comment: it's actually in this case not less code...

Answer (score 0):

You need body and onload event, please check: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp

Comment: please never link to that site - here is why: http://www.w3fools.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
  alert("hello"); //call your function here
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `onload` in body

eg.

```
<body onload="ip(parameters)">

</body>
```